# how to get activity to start another activity through onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

This is a very specific need I have. And there are reasons for it. The question is as simple as stated in the title: I have many activities in my project. But for activities DogActivity and CatActivity. I would like when DogActivity starts CatActivity, for CatActivity to see if as if called through onActivityResult as opposed to onCreate. Is this possible? Any example code?

**EDIT**

Two of the lifecycle methods of an activity that can be overridden are `onCreate` and `onActivityResult`. If CatActivity were to start DogActivity with `startActivityForResult`, then naturally when DogActivity finishes, CatActivity's `onActivityResult` method is called.

In my scenario, CatActivity is NOT the one that started DocActivity; on the contrary, I need DogActivity to start CatActivity. But when DogActivity starts CatActivity, I would have to have CatActivity behave as though DogActivity were returning to CatActivity's `onActivityResult`. So instead of going through `onCreate`, I want it to go through `onActivityResult`. Hence my question: is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just add an Extra when calling the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, class);
intent.putExtra("from_activity_result", true);
```

And then in the receiving Activity, you can call:

```
getIntent().getBooleanExtra("from_activity_result", false);
```

If it's true, then you know it came from the onActivityResult method. If not, you know it didn't.

Comment: Please see my edit section. I don't think you understood the question the first time.

Comment: No, that's exactly what it's for. If getIntent().getBooleanExtra("from_activity_result", false) == false, then it means it did NOT come from CatActivity, and DogActivity must start it. Unless your question is you want onCreate NOT to be called, which is absolutely NOT possible.